# How to test 10 gigabit Intel X520 on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, arp

I got Intel X520 and connected it to PCI-E x16. The card is recognized as 10 Gbit by ethtool:

```
 # ethtool eth5
Settings for eth5:
        Supported ports: [ FIBRE ]
        Supported link modes:   1000baseT/Full 
                                10000baseT/Full 
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised link modes:  10000baseT/Full 
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Speed: 10000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: FIBRE
        PHYAD: 0
        Transceiver: external
        Auto-negotiation: on
        Supports Wake-on: d
        Wake-on: d
        Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
        Link detected: yes
```

The switch also recognizes the link as 10 Gbit. 
I ran `iperf` tests from 12 different machines (2 times x 6). Every single connection is 1 Gbit, except the server one. So, I expect to see around 6 Gbit total (6 machines x 1 Gbit each). I got only total of 1 Gbit on the server side. 
My questions are:

1. am I doing something wrong?
2. how to properly test the new card?

The OS is Ubuntu Karmic, the MB is Supermicro X8DAi. 
Thanks!

EDIT:
The switch is single [Netgear GSM7328S-200NAS](http://www.netgear.com/business/products/switches/fully-managed-switches/gsm7328s-200.aspx). Here is a diagram:
[image: 6 1 Gbps Clients to 10 Gbps server]

I test by running:

```
Server: iperf -s
All clients, simultaneously: iperf -c server_IP
```

I see values around 150-160 Mbps/client, which match to 1 Gbps link to the server. The IP I assigned to the new card was never used, so I suppose no ARP issues. However, all traffic is on one subnet, as the same clients use the old 1 Gbps card and IP of the server.

No virtualization here, just plain Ubuntu install, serving NFS mostly.

Update: after further tests, I found that the clients' ARP tables contain wrong entry for server's 10 Gbps NIC. The HW address listed there is the same as the server's 1 Gbps NIC. I deleted it and manually inserted the correct entry: `arp -d server_IP_10g`, `arp -s server_IP_10g HW:address`. After that I was unable to `ping server_IP_10g`.

How can I fix it without disabling the 1 Gbps NIC in the server?

UPDATE2: `sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_ignore=1
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_announce=2` does not work.

Comment: Can you provide more details about the switching hardware involved and how the servers are interconnected on that switching hardware(which blades, trunks, supervisors, etc)?

Comment: Could you also describe your test methodology? It's not quite clear.

Comment: @polynomial - I updated my question to provide the requested info. Thanks!

Comment: @sybreon - I updated my question to provide the requested info. Thanks!

Comment: could you post your /etc/network/interfaces file?

Comment: @Brian: 
`# The secondary network interface

auto eth3

iface eth3 inet static

address server_IP_1G

netmask XX.XX.XX.XX

mtu 9000`

The 10 Gbps isn't listed there, as I need to run tests on it beforehand. However, this is its config:
`iface eth5 inet static

address server_IP_10G

netmask XX.XX.XX.XX

mtu 9000`.

Both netmasks are the same, both interfaces are on the same subnet, no virtual interfaces.

Comment: You may find my question at http://serverfault.com/questions/254773/specifying-a-preferred-route-when-there-are-multiple-links-to-same-network helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After carefully revising pros and cons and what actually is possible to test, I went and disabled `eth3` on the server (the 1 Gbps NIC) and set up `eth5` (the 10 Gbps) with its address. Then the clients found the new interface and `iperf` showed 10 Gbps from 10 x 1 Gbps clients. So, all is good. 
I think @sciurus' question, posted above, would be great, if I needed both interfaces permanently. +1 from me on the good reference!

Comment: +1 for coming back and answering your question for future people to find!